# Vector of vector storage limitations - getting "Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0031650C." error

Tags: c++, vector

In C++ I am reading in several large gridded datasets for processing.  Recently, one of these data sets broke my code before I even got to the processing.

The data set had 5765 cols and 5872 rows for a total of 33852080 cells.  Well under the individual vector capacity limit for a double, right?  Or not?  I'm trying to figure that out currently.

The exception is thrown trying to push_back the inner 2496th vector into the original vectors.

Here's the code:

```
slopeGrid.reserve(rows);  
flowDirGrid.reserve(rows);     
flowAccumGrid.reserve(rows);  
tempGrid.reserve(rows);
inflowGrid.reserve(rows);
TWIgrid.reserve(rows);


for(int k=0; k<rows; k++)
{
    elevation.push_back(*new vector<double>(cols));
    ATB.push_back(*new vector<double>(cols));
    Area.push_back(*new vector<double>(cols));

    slopeGrid.push_back(*new vector<double>(cols));   
    flowDirGrid.push_back(*new vector<double>(cols));     
    flowAccumGrid.push_back(*new vector<double>(cols));   
    tempGrid.push_back(*new vector<double>(cols));
    inflowGrid.push_back(*new vector<double>(cols));
    TWIgrid.push_back(*new vector<double>(cols));

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `elevation.push_back(*new vector<double>(cols));` instead of `elevation.push_back(vector<double>(cols));` ? You are leaking the `new`ed object using the first method.

Comment: I second R Sahu, dynamically allocating `vector`s somehow defeats their purpose. Besides, you should probably use `resize` rather than a loop of `push_back` (and if you're adamant about using dynamic allocation, initialize the pointers afterwards).

Comment: It is a good question. It is because somebody at some point told me to do that. Here's a follow-up question: since I know my rows and cols beforehand, is it faster and better to just reserve a two-dimensional vector out right?

Comment: @traggatmot, that will be better than adding one item at a time.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Now to figure out how to do that.....googling.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 34 millions objects, right?  If enough of those objects are big enough I think reaching the maximum of 2 gigs per Windows 32 bit process wouldn't be that hard...

Comment: That's true, I do have that many objects. Does it change if I'm running 64bit windows 7??

Comment: Only if the program you're creating is being built as a 64-bit executable.  That said, the above approach seems really sub-optimal.  Is there really no other way to do it?  BTW, removing all of the '*new' sequences might also help a bit

Comment: I still ran into memory exception when the having removed the dynamic allocation.  Using this format "slopeGrid.resize(rows, std::vector<double>(cols, NODATA));" I still run into the problem.  I need those 34 million cells initialized......that is unless I change my input resolution......

Comment: And there's no way to, for example, create enough arrays and whatnot for the first 1000 rows, do all the calculations you need to do on those 1000 rows, save those results, then reuse (by refilling) those rows for the 1001st to 2000th row, etc?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  The gridded input is an elevation file, and all the 2D vectors I am creating is the results of analyzing continuous pathways between cells in the grid.  There is and "end" cell, and thousands of start cells.  In my analysis, I do a depth first search for/along these pathways.  In the analysis, I limit the pathway length to 10,000 cells (kind of arbitrary, haven't worked out the limit based on computing resources), but I need all those cells because the pathways start and end at random places within my grid.

Answer (score 0):

What worked:

I still ran into memory exception when the having removed the dynamic allocation, and using this format:

```
elevation.resize(rows, std::vector<double>(cols, NODATA));
```

But then, based on Tive's answer I was able to locate and follow this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx

And that fixed it and got it working.