# How to compare 2D vector size with OS memory address limitations?

Tags: c++, vector, double, out-of-memory

I ran into a memory exception when creating 2D vectors, from a gridded data set that I was reading in.  I was attempting to store 34 million double values.  Here is the previous question where I and others solved that problem:

[Vector of vector storage limitations - getting "Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0031650C." error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32018208/1762492)

Basically I set the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE option in the linker system settings in Visual Studio to "Yes" that fixed it and got it working.

Questions:  If I want to pre-calculate the size of the gridded data set and warn the user that they need to shrink their inputs, how do I:

1. Calculate the size of my 2D vectors (which store double values) once I know their dimensions?
2. Determine how many 2D vectors of this size I can create?  Right now I need to create about 10.
3. Determine the max size of the memory allocation with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE set to "Yes"?
4. Compare the two.

Thanks.

Comment: The code in that question literally leaks memory like a sieve leaks rain water, as pointed out by Sahu.  Even in a 32 bit process, 34,000,000 double values only occupy ~260MB of memory, far under the 2GB limit. Fixing the memory leaks will go a ton further to fix your problem than anything else. And LAA can be taken off the block too if you build a 64bit process

Comment: I think I fixed the memory leaks. Check out the solution I posted.  The thing was, even after resizing the vectors with my known rows and columns, it would still crash after the 7th or 8th vector was resized.

Comment: @WhozCraig, traggatmot says he needs about 10 of those vectors. ~2600MB is not under the 2GB limit.

Comment: @traggatmot That is mucho better. If you indeed need 10 of those bad-boys is there something limiting you to a 32bit process only? A 64-bit process should man-handle that need.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think the only thing that might limit me to 32-bit process is my knowledge?  I am running VS 21012 on a MacBook within 64bit windows 7.

Comment: Its a separate issue from your question, and I apologize for that. Not all code-functioning-fine in 32bit land is automagically 64bit compatible (though if you stuck close to the language standard, it will stand a good chance). Using 3rd party libraries that are only 32bit is one obvious place where going the 64bit route has the wheels fall off. If your app is stand-alone (no 3rd party) adding a build platform for x64 is pretty simple ([see here for a wee bit of info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms165408(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: Thanks, it is stand alone so I will look into it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `bytes_per_vector = m * (sizeof vector<double> + n * sizeof double)`
   Where `m` and `n` are the dimensions of the vectors.
2. `fits_in_memory = free_bytes / bytes_per_vector`
3. There is no standard way to get the amount of free memory left in c++. [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be of use for a rough estimate but realize that there is probably other things in your program that use the memory too and there are other programs running as well.
4. If you have the amount of free bytes and the bytes that you need, then you can use the "less than"-operator: `<`

I recommend that you simply report the user how much memory the vectors are going to use and let them worry about having enough free memory.